# no overload for the 'tostring' method ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this code and I am giving this error in which I can not solve.

code:

```
  public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        DateTime data = context.Reserva.Select(x => x.DataEntrada).ToString("MMMM");
        int ID = context.Reserva.Select(x => x.ID_Cliente).Count();
        Reserva obj = new Reserva();
        obj.DataEntrada = data;
        obj.ID_Cliente = ID;
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here: DateTime data = context.Reserva.Select(x => x.DataEntrada).ToString("MMMM");

When running the code, I get this error:

```
no overload for the 'toString' method
```

Model

```
namespace WebApplication.Models.BaseDados
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Reserva
    {
        public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }
        public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }
        public string TipoQuarto { get; set; }
        public int NumeroQuarto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
        public string Observaçoes { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Because your query is generating `IEnumerable<DateTime>` (a collection,  not a single `DateTime`). Its not clear what you want the output to be.

Comment: Overload not overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `context.Reserva` is indeed `Reserva` type. 
You don't even need `Select`, so just access the `DataEntrada` property directly. `DataEntrada` is type of `DateTime`, so you don't convert it `ToString`

```
DateTime data = context.Reserva.DataEntrada;
```

Also (not related to your question) as the follow up, the line after that is also wrong.

```
int ID = context.Reserva.ID_Cliente;
```

Comment: `context.Reserva` returns a collection of `Reserva` (which does not have a property named `DataEntrada` or `ID_Cliente`)